# Ajax Loading Indicator only works the first time and then the indicator does not appear

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code where everything works fine except for the loading indicator which works only the very first time I click on the search button, but after the first event, it never appears back again and I cannot figure out what am I missing here:

Could someone please help?

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <section id="Search">
            <hr />

            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                @Html.Label("Clinic Code:", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                @Html.TextBox("ClinicCode", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

                    </div>

                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
     <div id="partial">
      @Html.Partial("_PartialDetails", Model)
     </div>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none">
       <img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
@section Scripts {    
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function () {
            // show gif here, eg:
            $("#loading").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            // hide gif here, eg:
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
});

     $('#searchButton').click(function (e) {
        searchReferrals(e);
    });

}
```

---app.js file loaded through masterpage

```
 function searchReferrals(e) {


        $.ajax({
            url: "/Demo/GetReferralDetails/",
            data: {ClinicCode: ClinicCode, },
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#partial').html("");
                $("#partial").html(result);

                $('#checkall').on('click', function () {
                    var chk = $(this).is(':checked');
                    $('input[type=checkbox]', "#Data").each(function () {
                        if (chk) {

                            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                        }
                    });

                });

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#partial").html("");
                $('#partial').html('<p>status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>' + jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
        });
}
```

}

Comment: any console errors when you trigger the second ajax

Comment: @madalinivascu: no nothing. i am looking for clues as well but can;t find anything obvious

Comment: are you sure #loading isn't part of #partial ,maby its removing the div when you clear it in the ajax

Comment: you were right. even though its not part of partial but somehow its being cleared. i moved the location of loading and now it all works fine. very strange though as they are independent divs. could you please reply with this as answer and i will accept it. would you also know why would it be clearing any div?

Comment: its clearing the loading div because you are not properly closing the elements in your `#partial` element, so a closing tag will move from the loading div to another div that you haven't closed making your loading div a child of #partial

Comment: i figured it out. it was still displaying the loading indicator but because after the first call, the data is displayed, the indicator is no longer visible where it was used to be and it was being displayed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: you can inspect the cause in the developer tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#loading` may be part of `#partial`, when you do the clearing of `#partial` in the ajax you will delete the #loading div, make sure you properly close your divs in your `#partial`

Comment: i figured it out. it was still displaying the loading indicator but because after the first call, the data is displayed, the indicator is no longer visible where it was used to be and it was being displayed at the bottom of the page as the indicator was after the partial page div.